# Publish a TypeScript Project to NPM without source

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

**Problem:** I have built a library that have many `.ts` files in structured folders. Now I want to publish my this library, but do not want to share Source (typescript files).

**Attempt:** When I run `tsc` command it generates a `.js` file corresponding to each `.ts` file. When I keep `declaration: true` in my `tsconfig.json` file then `tsc` also generates `.d.ts` file for each `.ts` file as well.

**Challenge:** All of my `.js` files are generated structurally as expected, but `.d.ts` also are generating in parallel location of `.js` file. Now challenge is, by this way how any consumer of this library will import types as all of them are scattered in different folders, as there is no single `.d.ts` file generated by `tsc`

I see many module on NPM (like https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) which publishes single `index.d.ts` file, and consumer import them to use and avail Typescript advantage.

Currently my project structure looks like as below:

```
- my-project-root-directory
    - src
        - demo
            - main.ts
            - sample.ts
        -lib
            - constants
                - some_constant_file1.ts
            - models
                - some_model_file1.ts
                - some_model_file2.ts
            - util
                - some_util_file.ts
    - dist
        - demo
            - main.js
            - main.d.ts
            - sample.js
            - sample.d.ts
        -lib
            - constants
                - some_constant_file1.js
                - some_constant_file1.d.ts
            - models
                - some_model_file1.js
                - some_model_file1.d.ts
                - some_model_file2.js
                - some_model_file2.d.ts
            - util
                - some_util_file.js
                - some_util_file.d.ts
    - logs
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

There is obviously no `index.d.ts` file, how can I get single file? Is single `.d.ts` file approach correct way? Or I am moving into wrong direction?

I've already seen many answers on stackoverflow & tutorials on youtube, all of them showing a simple example which have only single index.ts file and index.d.ts file corresponding to it. But I can not find a perfect way that solve my purpose.

Thanks for reading my question, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd go along:

1. Create an `index.ts` file in each folder that exports types that are meaningful for library consumers. For example: `src/lib/constants/index.ts`, `src/lib/models/index.ts`, ... Each of the `index.ts` files exports all TypeScript types that exist in its folder, plus all `index.ts` files from its sub-folders.
2. Create a central `src/index.ts` file that exports everything from all `src/...` subfolders.
3. In your `package.json`, add a `types: "dist/index.d.ts"` entry.
4. In your `.npmignore` file, add a a `src/` entry.

With this approach, you have all your imports referenced in one central `dist/index.d.ts` file, so consumers of your library do not need to import types from different locations inside your package. Also, you do not distribute TypeScript sources at all.

---

Here's how your directory structure could end up looking like. I excluded the `dist` folder, but an `index.js` and `index.d.ts` file will be generated in each folder, as well:

```
- my-project-root-directory
    - src
        - index.ts
        - demo
            - main.ts
            - sample.ts
        -lib
            - constants
                - some_constant_file1.ts
                - index.ts
            - models
                - some_model_file1.ts
                - some_model_file2.ts
                - index.ts
            - util
                - some_util_file.ts
                - index.ts
    - logs
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
```

Your `src/lib/constants/index.ts` file could, for example, look like this:

```
export * from './some_constant_file1.ts'
```

Your `src/lib/index.ts` file:

```
export * from './constants';
export * from './models';
export * from './util';
```

Your `src/index.ts` file:

```
export * from './lib';
```

Comment: Might want to note that in the tsconfig you have outDir which determines the output of the files. You can copy the package.json in to that folder and just npm publish ./dist without the .ts files

Comment: @misha130: I've seen that approach and can see the charm, however I saw more challenges with it: You need a build step to actively copy `package.json` after building the ts sources, or you need to maintain two separate `package.json` files, one for dist and one for the entire project, which can become a hassle as normally you'll want to keep `dist` inside your `.gitignore`.

Comment: @fjc I appreciate your answer. When I am following your way, tsc still generating .ts file for all files like 
`- some_constant_file1.js`
`- some_constant_file1.d.ts`
`- index.d.ts`
do I need to bother about it as it is generating more d.ts file foreach .ts file while we will also make `index.ts` in src and `index.d.ts` in dist for each folder?

Comment: Hey Rahul, it's just definition files that are referenced by index.d.ts. There's nothing wrong with shipping them and this is a pretty standard way of doing it, so I don't see an issue here.

Comment: @fjc alright, but there is one more issue I caught up with, I have .ts files with `export namespace` within it, so when I follow your approach (index.ts thing), it says `Module "./some_model_file1" has already exported a member named 'my_namespace'. Consider explicitly re-exporting to resolve the ambiguity.`, any help on this?

Comment: Do you need that namespace export or can you go without? It sounds like everything is being exported via the `index.ts` files already.

Comment: @fjc I need my namespace exported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193985/discussion-between-rahul-verma-and-fjc).